# how to backup mysql database outside phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm currently using the export function in phpmyadmin to update mysql database. How do I do it outside phpmyadmin, is there any other application that could do this?

Answer (score 4):

do you have shell access to the machine?  there's a [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) command that you can run that will dump your database for you.  A lot of the packages that let you get access to an 'export' are actually calling mysqldump under the covers.

Here's an example of restoring an export from phpmyadmin with a [mysqldump](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php).  This sort of thing works well.  If this isn't the sort of information you're looking for, you should be more specific about what sort of application you want.